# Mother/Father/Children relationships in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I am pretty sure this is a pretty basic question. anyway I don't find the right information to get going.

I have got 3 models.

Users - Tasks - Notes

Users and Tasks are on the same level, as tasks are children of the Projects model, and they function as a template.
Then for each user I display all the tasks of the project and add notes.
Notes in this case are children of BOTH Users and Tasks, actually they are children of the combination of the two.

What is the best way to tackle this problem? I checked out polymorphic associations and doesn't seem it will work in this case.

Cheers,
Davide

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand of your problem polymorphic associations are exactly what you want, being that Users have many Notes, and Tasks have many Notes.

The relationships would look like this

in both user.rb and task.rb

```
has_many :notes, :as => :noteable
```

in note.rb

```
belongs_to :noteable, :polymorphic => true
```

in your create notes migration

```
t.references :noteable, :polymorphic => true
```

Note both Users and Tasks can have Notes, and Notes can belong to either a User or a Task (or anything else that connects using the noteable polymorphic interface).

Comment: The reason why I am saying polymorphic won't work for me is that the COMBINATION of a specific user and a specific task, can have many notes. From my understanding polymorphic association are set up in a way that a note has either a user or a task as a parent.